# Spring Boot MVC Remote Templates

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to put our templates folder in a remote host like `aws-s3`, currently 
 using a custom `urlTemplateResolver` and using the `thymeleaf` **replace** tag.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringTemplateConfiguration {
   private final SpringResourceTemplateResolver springResourceTemplateResolver;

   @Value("${spring.thymeleaf.cache}")
   Boolean springThymeleafCache;

   public SpringTemplateConfiguration(SpringResourceTemplateResolver springResourceTemplateResolver) {
       this.springResourceTemplateResolver = springResourceTemplateResolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
       SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

       UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver = new UrlTemplateResolver();
       urlTemplateResolver.setCacheable(springThymeleafCache); // explicit set cacheable, otherwise it will be always cached

       templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(urlTemplateResolver);
       templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(springResourceTemplateResolver);

       return templateEngine;
   }
}
```

and this is the thymeleaf template

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="~{${url} :: html}">
</html>
```

is there another way to just use the templates folder from the remote host and just return the view name from the controller ??

It is possible to use another external location but not remote location which doesn't solve our problem.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of the `UrlTemplateResolver` in the first place? Add a proper prefix and suffix and it should obtain them from the S3 store. Also You should only register the `UrlTemplateResolver` as an `@Bean` and the default configuration will detect and use that resolver as well.

Comment: yes thats true it worked i tried it before but it looks like i put wrong params, this is part of the solution since im going to need to find a way to generate signed s3 url because i dont want to put the files in the bucket to public access.
thank you for pointing me to the right direction :)

Comment: Or write a custom `ITemplateResolver` which uses AWS underneath, using the AWS SDK. That way you won't need the signed URLs I guess.

Comment: that doesnt apply on static resources right ? i cant make the template engine serve static resrouces like css and js files with a custom resolver

Comment: Sure why not. You can also write a `ResourceResolver` (Spring class) based on AWS as well. On the other hand when you start doing that for more things you might also include Spring Cloud AWS on your classpath which enables support for `s3:` URLs which will be resolved on amazon.